# How to import a preference file in eclipse with the launch of eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have to import a eclipse preference file within my application. But I want to do it while my application launches means whenever I launch my application it should import the preference file. Is it possible?

Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is possible...

You might also want to have a look at [Workspace Mechanic for Eclipse](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/workspacemechanic/):

> The Workspace Mechanic automates maintenance of your Eclipse environment by tweaking preferences, adding extension locations, and so on. You can use it to:
>
> - Create a consistent environment among groups as large as the entire company, your local team, or even among your own many workspaces
> - Save time setting up new workspaces
> - Create tasks that ensure your favorite new preferences are applied to all your current and future workspaces. (This is one of our favorite features!)